# mySQL Command Line Import CSV Gives me NULL

Tags: mysql, csv

I am used to using PHPmyadmin to manage my mySQL databases but I am starting to use the command line a lot more.  I am trying to import a CSV file into a table called source_data that looks like this...

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| result    | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| source    | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And my CSV file looks like this...

```
code,result,source,timestamp
123 ABC,,,
456 DEF,,,
789 GHI,,,
234 JKL,,,
567 MNO,,,
890 PQR,,,
```

I am using this command..

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/user1/data.csv' INTO TABLE source_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

This inserts the correct number of rows but each one just says NULL, where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is happening due to auto_increment column in your table I believe. Please see this thread on how to import data with auto_increment column in  the table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463542/how-to-import-text-file-to-table-with-primary-key-as-auto-increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the CSV file doesn't have all the table columns (it's missing the `id` column), you need to specify the columns that they should be written into explicitly.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/user1/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE source_data 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(code, result, source, timestamp);
```

Comment: I am getting an error trying to run that query,  right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, the column list has to be at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I hope this wouldn't be a case still, You said table name is **source_data** and in command the name is **data**

Comment: Then why is it inserting the correct number of rows?

Comment: Ya, Add comma before CODE column in csv, Right now you are entering only 4 columns rather than 5. The first column should be ID, whicha can be empty(cause its auto increment) but it should be there to load the data.

Comment: try @Barmar 's solution