# Auto increment column in mysql when importing with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in mysql with the following headings:

```
staff_id,dept_id,role_id,username,firstname,lastname,passwd,backend,email,phone,phone_ext,mobile,signature,lang,timezone,locale,notes,isactive,isadmin,isvisible,onvacation,assigned_only,show_assigned_tickets,change_passwd,max_page_size,auto_refresh_rate,default_signature_type,default_paper_size,extra,permissions,created,lastlogin,passwdreset,updated
```

`staff_id` is a primary key value and is set to AUTO_INCREMENT.

I found the solution by Queue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463542/how-to-import-text-file-to-table-with-primary-key-as-auto-increment) really helpful, although when the data is being imported the staff_id column is not being auto-incremented. I am inserting the column names in the Format-Specific Options in phpmysql. I can only get it to populate if the staff_id value exists in the csv file I am trying to import.

So if the data looks like this:

```
2,1,1,agent,Mista,Busta,NULL,NULL,agent@company.org,,NULL,,,NULL,NULL,NULL,<p>this is an agent; mista busta; agent@company.org</p>,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,none,Letter,"{""def_assn_role"":true}","{""user.create"":1,""user.delete"":1,""user.edit"":1,""user.manage"":1,""user.dir"":1,""org.create"":1,""org.delete"":1,""org.edit"":1,""faq.manage"":1}",2020-02-04 10:18:42,NULL,NULL,2020-02-04 10:18:42
```

...note the first '2' is the staff_id. What I would like do is have this in the csv:

```
,1,1,agent,Mista,Busta,NULL,NULL,agent@company.org,,NULL,,,NULL,NULL,NULL,<p>this is an agent; mista busta; agent@company.org</p>,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,none,Letter,"{""def_assn_role"":true}","{""user.create"":1,""user.delete"":1,""user.edit"":1,""user.manage"":1,""user.dir"":1,""org.create"":1,""org.delete"":1,""org.edit"":1,""faq.manage"":1}",2020-02-04 10:18:42,NULL,NULL,2020-02-04 10:18:42
```

...leaving the staff_id column blank and allowing mysql to auto-populate (auto_increment) as it sees fit.

Comment: Do not leave staff_id blank, it's a required field --  Instead remove it completely (including the comma)  --  Also make sure you remove the reference to staff_id in the actual insert statement if applicable. (IE simply removing the entire column, including header .. )  -- MySQL will see no reference to it during import, and obey the "auto increment", assigning new IDs

Comment: Create `staff_id` as simple non-indexed field,import the data as is, then drop `staff_id` and create as needed - auto_increment, primary key and so on.

Comment: @Zak right on bro! That worked. Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: NULL also will be replaced to auto increment value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTO INCREMENT` is set at the server level within MySQL, and *can* be overwritten if assigned manually within a CSV or other import.  If you simply exclude the entire column from your import, you'll allow MySQL to do what is set as *default* for that column, and automatically assign ID's, since it doesn't think you want to assign them yourself.

Also as a side note, if you import more than once without using `TRUNCATE TABLE` --  MySQL will pick up on the last inserted ID and move on from there, even if the table is empty.  So if you ever want to start over from *1* you'll have to trucate the table.